# Reading Cookie Data from Different Subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I have an ASP.Net application that creates a cookie on domain1.mywebsite.com.

```
Private Sub CreateCookie()
    If Request.Cookies("D1_MyWebSite") Is Nothing Then
        Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("D1_MyWebSite")
        aCookie.Path = "/"
        aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString
        aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
        Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
    Else
        Dim cookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("D1_MyWebSite")
        cookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
    End If
End Sub
```

On domain2.mywebsite.com, I am trying to read the value that is saved in the cookie using jQuery.
The web page address is domain2.mywebsite.com/index.html but the source of my .js files for this page are :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://domain1.mywebsite.com/js/jumppage.js"></script>
<script src="https://domain1.mywebsite.com/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

I've tried using the following to get the value of the domain1.mywebsite.com D1_MyWebSite cookie, but all it does is create a new cookie named D1_MyWebSite for domain2.mywebsite.com. How can I get the cookie value for the domain1.mywebsite.com D1_MyWebSiteCookie?

```
    $.cookie("D1_MyWebSite", "value");
```

Comment: Update: I have replaced aCookie.Path = "/" with aCookie.Domain=".mywebsite.com". Now that I've done this, it creates a cookie for mywebsite.com , but I still cannot access it with jQuery. My jQuery code continues to create a D1_MyWebSite cookie for domain2.mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue. I had to remove the .Path and add .Domain.

```
    Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("D1_MyWebSite")
    aCookie.Domain = ".mywebsite.com"
    aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString
```

I was able to get the datetime value stored in the cookie on domain2 with jQuery by using the following code:

```
    var MyValue = $.cookie("D1_MyWebSite");
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the path to "/", as in

```
aCookie.Path = "/";
```

Comment: Sorry, the "/" somehow got removed from the original post. I have since fixed the typo. The aCookie.Path = "/" does not seem to make a difference.